# Views: if fieldvalue (external link) is set, use it, if not, link to node

Tags: views

For my articles, i've added a field "external_link". If this link is set, the headline should link to an external website, and if not, the headline should open the articles detailview.

Now i have the fields of my view two fields, which are excluded from the display, the external_link, and the nid. And on the headlinefield, i can do a

"rewrite results -> output this field as a link" 
and write either node/[nid] or [external_link],

but how to use conditions in views, to use the external_link if set, and the node/[nid] if not set? I'm new to Drupal and i have no idea how or where to add this condition...

Comment: I asked basically the same thing last week -- [see the answer i approved in the other thread][1].


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/40207/3279

Comment: thanks for the link and your answer, i think the other way was easier in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way of using conditionals inside of Views.  However, you *might* be able to fake it out with something like this:

1. Order the fields in your view in nid, external link, title order.
2. In your external link field, set empty field behavior to node/[nid]
3. Always use it as the link in the last rewrite.

In my just woke up and enjoying espresso before getting to some real work state of mind, this *should* do what you are asking for, eg, linking to node/nid if there is no external link, but using it if it exists.

Comment: thanks a lot, it helped me out, finally i used [path] (and added some additional settings like: use absolute url to remove double slashes when used in field-empty-behaviour)

Comment: glad I could help out